# Is it possible to do probability calibration in TFX?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, calibration

I am interested in [calibrating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibration_(statistics)) a binary probabilistic classifier in TFX. I was about to try doing it in standard Python externally to TFX, but then I found this [piecewise linear calibration layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/lattice/api_docs/python/tfl/layers/PWLCalibration).

The description is a bit cryptic to me. Is this layer the sort of thing one could stack to the output layer of a TFX model and calibrate the output using recent `y_true` and `y_pred`?

If not, is there a standard way to do calibration in TFX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calibration of the data should be done prior to the data the transformation and classification.

The piecewise data is only applicable when the data coincides to regions of observed data.
We are not given enough information to properly answer this question.

Comment: It seems to me that you are referring to calibrating the features? I am asking about calibrating the model's output (which is a probability in the range [0,1]).

Comment: @user1337, This seems to be a terminology issue, Simply apply a correction function or additional model to the output.